# Swift how to implement macOS Finder's file downloading progress on file

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

it's looks like this
https://ibb.co/JysCH5v
https://ibb.co/H45b9xN

I've reference from here
[Can you implement OS X's Finder download progress bars from a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427421/can-you-implement-os-xs-finder-download-progress-bars-from-a-shell-script)

and here
https://gist.github.com/mminer/3c0fbece956f3a5fa795563fafb139ae

but both of them not work, 
Finder's file progress not show up, and nothing happen,

I'v intend to implement like safari file download, or google chrome file download effect,
every individual file will have progress bar on it, until file completed,

I'm not mean update progress on my own app view, it's on finder's file

I'm in macOS 10.14.5, Swift5

am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "not work" mean, exactly?

Comment: Finder's file progress not show up, and nothing happen

Comment: The Finder actually monitors the URL you pass to it. You can't simulate download progress. You have to actually write to the file.

Comment: @cool That example that was shown uses async tasks. If you're just running this in a script, repl or playground, the execution of the program will end before the async tasks ever fire. Could that be your issue, or have you already solved that?

Comment: You cannot control the progress window of the Finder. You have to create your own.

Comment: @vadian Yes you can. https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/53275fcda8f945dbdd67f3c1b8fd82df

Comment: @KenThomases Nope, you definitely can: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/53275fcda8f945dbdd67f3c1b8fd82df

Comment: @Alexander This is an **own** one.

Comment: @vadian I don't follow

Comment: @Alexander You are creating a custom progress window. This is **not** the progress window which belongs to the Finder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194504/discussion-between-alexander-and-vadian).

Comment: @Alexander Hi I try your new gist, it's still no any progress show up at finder's downloading file, I'v intend to implement like safari download, or google chrome download effect,

Comment: @cool What file did you provide for the `path` variable?

Comment: @Alexander "/Users/usr/Downloads/a.txt"

Comment: @cool And `a.txt` is a file you created, and `usr` is your account's username?

Comment: @Alexander yes,

Comment: @cool and you're running this code in a standalone swift file, that you're running with `swift` or `swiftc`?

Comment: @Alexander yes in swift

Comment: @cool Hmmm, well I'm out of ideas. Works fine for me, `Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)`

Comment: @Alexander  it's looks like this https://ibb.co/JysCH5v,  https://ibb.co/H45b9xN, what's your result screenshot?

Comment: @cool See my comment on https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/7a977b9f99e898f0ff5d8e500c213aef